# Spark Encoders generic class

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Encoders not working for generic type java bean

```
Class Account<T> {
  private String name;
  private T obj;

// getters & setters

}

Class PersonalAccount {

}
```

Read parquet file from HDFS

```
Dataset<Row> da =spark.read.parquet(“...”)
da.as(Encoders.bean(Account<PeronalAccount>.class) // not working
```

Any solutions?

Comment: if `PersonalAccount` is your Java Bean then you can try using Encoders.bean(PersonalAccount.class) instead. I am not sure why yoou have Account<T> in there so just a thought.